# Handling smaller trees representing branches of the big tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, branch

I have a very big tree. Is it problematic if instead of keeping that big tree my program concurrently handles many smaller trees representing branches of that big tree?

Knowing I wouldn’t decide where the branches are cut from to make this the most efficiently but this would be imposed on me (so I’d end up dealing with many smaller trees of unequal size pointing to each other). The goal is to handle the capacity of the same branches (not copies of their contents nor links) to concurently exist at different locations in the tree.

Comment: Are you thinking of a recursive [divide and conquer algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm)? If so, then that is not at all problematic - quite the opposite! Otherwise, could you maybe add some code / pseudo code that demonstrates what you are trying to do?

Comment: @runcoderun Branches would be iterated upon by a human user, nodes added or deleted, children re-ordered under their parent, entire branches moved, searches be made for information contained in nodes on the tree, computations made from data stored at nodes distributed across the tree, etc. Nodes would consist of a set of data (a small table perhaps). I´m trying to figure out what data structure to use so that some branches can concurrently be present at several locations in the tree all the while maximising performance/efficiency/simplicity for the aforementioned routine manipulations.